# SQL : how to find gaps in a specific range of numbers?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to find gaps in a numeric column (not the entire column), but in a *specific range*.

For example :
My column :

```
1
2
5
6
8
10
18
19
20
```

I want to specify a specific range in which my SQL query would look for gaps. For example, I want gaps in the range [15,20]. In this example, the gaps are : 15,16,17.

I built a query that retrieves gaps but not in case the gaps are at the beginning of my range

```
SELECT cur_value + 1 AS start_gap, next_value - 1 AS end_gap
FROM (
  SELECT col AS cur_value, LEAD (col) OVER (ORDER BY col) AS next_value
  FROM table
  --WHERE col BETWEEN 200 AND 300
)
WHERE next_value - cur_value > 1
ORDER BY start_gap;
```

How can I do that ?

**N.B : Performance is very important in my case. I deal with tons of rows.**

Comment: What does any of this have to do with pl/sql? Or with "gaps-and-islands"? (Perhaps the tag was added automatically; it doesn't belong).

Comment: The tag has been modified by a 'moderator'.. I don't know why...

Comment: Sherlock: is at least the Oracle tag correct? (Although this problem would be solved the same way in any database product.)

Comment: @mathguy : yes it is, thanks

Comment: "Tons" is not a measure of a number of rows. Please enumerate.

Answer (score 4):

I think the simplest method might be:

```
SELECT cur_value + 1 AS start_gap, next_value - 1 AS end_gap
FROM (SELECT col AS cur_value, LEAD (col) OVER (ORDER BY col) AS next_value
      FROM (SELECT col
            FROM table
            WHERE col BETWEEN 200 AND 300
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 200-1 FROM DUAL
            UNION ALL
            SELECT 300+1 FROM DUAL
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE next_value - cur_value > 1
ORDER BY start_gap;
```

Note:  This will work on arbitrarily long ranges.

Comment: Thank you. In terms of performance, do you think your query is faster than GurV's ?

Comment: Gordon, does this solution work using the example data posted, but using the range [1:20]?

Comment: @BobC . . . It should.  By adding in additional rows on the boundary of the range, you should be able to do what the OP wants.  As for performance, I don't know.  For small ranges, the `connect` might be fine.  I suspect that for larger ranges, this would be much better.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Yup, my bad. I had a typo when I was trying your solution. The connect-by solution ran out of memory at about 1.3M rows; admittedly on my small development server...

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use hierarchical `connect by` to produce the list of numbers in the given range and then check to see if the value doesn't exist in the table.

Assuming your range is 15 to 20, use `NOT IN`:

```
select * from (
    select level - 1 + 15 col
    from dual
    connect by level <= 20 - 15
) where col not in (select col from your_table);
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/KYDT48755)

Similarly, `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select * from (
    select level - 1 + 15 col
    from dual
    connect by level <= 20 - 15
) t where not exists (select 1 from your_table where col = t.col);
```

#### [Demo 2](http://rextester.com/OSL59800)

Comment: @Sherlock - and why do you think that? It should be pretty fast.

Comment: The use of 'connect by' and the last select.. Aren't they heavy ?

Comment: For your case, it should be fine. However, don't take my word for it. Test it yourself and see which one is faster.

Comment: You could hit memory issue if you need to generate a large range using the CONNECT BY

Comment: Maybe I need to do this to get the last number : `connect by level <= 20 - 15 + 1` ?

Comment: As for performance, I have an index on the column, so it's fine